# Property is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In this react app there is a form with a few input fields. These fields all use `this.handleChange` with the `onChange` attribute.

```
private handleChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value
    });
};
```

The typescript error I get is:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/FormSubmitHighScore.tsx:43:23 
TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<State, "first_name" | "last_name" | "email_address" | "school_name" | "region" | "submitted">'.
Property 'first_name' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }'.
```

So by setting the state name field dynamically (based on what input is being used) this Typescript error gets triggered (but it does work in the browser).

How would I specify a correct type in this context?

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately until [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) [bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15534) are fixed - you have to go with some ugly workarounds like:

```
this.setState({
    [target.name]: target.value
} as any);
```

Comment: Nasty. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 13):

To avoid "any" linter warning I use:

```
this.setState({
  [target.name]: target.value
} as Pick<State, keyof State>);
```

Comment: this not works if value not string. At least, when value can be numeric

Answer (score 3):

Passing a function to setState works too. My guess is that it is because you are spreading state, so typescript knows it has all the properties of state.

```js
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
    }));
```

I was getting a similar error to what you were getting. Here is my implementation for a change handler:

```
  onChange = (name: keyof ComponentState, value: any) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was managing my props using `react` with `typescript` as a programming language. I was using `CBC` so i manage to get a work around on this by setting the state values to be optional. Here is my class based component where i'm getting track of the state of `username`, `email` and `password`:

```
interface Props {}
interface State {
  username?: string;
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
}
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      email: "",
    };
  }

  onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const { username, password, email } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="username"
            name="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

By setting fields optional in the `State` type you don't need to do this:

```
this.setState({
    [name]: value
} as any);
```

Because `typescript` knows how to handle this.