# Why TypeScript judge 'a' | 'b' to string?

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, React and English,sorry for ambiguity.I write a Function like this:

```
interface ObjectAttrUniqueState {
  editVisible: boolean;
  currentId: number;
  selectedUnique: number[];
  name: string;
  desc: string;
}

// some other code.....

handleChangeForm(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, attr: 'desc' | 'name') {
  this.setState({
    [attr]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

TypeScript output that:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ObjectAttrUniqueState, "editVisible" | "currentId" | "selectedUnique" | "name" | "desc">': editVisible, currentId, selectedUnique, name, desc
```

I tried this works

```
handleChangeForm(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, attr: 'name') {
  this.setState({
    [attr]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

I think that TypeScript judge 'name' to a simple string identifier, judge 'name'|'desc' to type string,that lead to this type error info.
So how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your object to `any` like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46363303/9124424

To avoid the `any`-warning you can cast to `Pick<State, keyof State>` like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481975/9124424

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue why it works for the second. It should not for both. The issue really is that you should put the whole object into `setState` and what you do is you put new object with one field, it does not match the state interface.

To describe that more, its just `setState(newState: ObjectAttrUniqueState )` and instead of that u use this like `setState(newState: Pick<ObjectAttrUniqueState, 'name' | 'desc'> )`. Which means you provide not enough data in the argument.

Solution is to copy previous state, and change only one wanted property:

```
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    [attr]: e.target.value,
  });
```

Comment: Hey, OP didn't mention that explicitly, but my guess is, class components are used in above sample. So passing a partial object to `this.setState` would be fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Say, there is a property name with union string literal type:

```
declare const aKey: "foo" | "bar"
```

, then you always get the type with index signature back, when a value is set via computed property name notation. The compiler doesn't know, which property actually has been accessed.

```
const o= { 
  [aKey]: true 
}; // o: { [x: string]: boolean }
```

Apparently there was a [Pull Request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21070) to narrow these types down a bit better, but it has never been merged (this [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030) is similar to yours). So you could cast the argument for `this.setState` as `any` or `Pick<ObjectAttrUniqueState, typeof attr>`.

```
handleChangeForm(
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    attr: "desc" | "name"
) {
    this.setState({
        [attr]: e.target.value
    } as Pick<ObjectAttrUniqueState, typeof attr>);
}
```

If needed, the key can be narrowed down to distinguish cases:

```
if (attr === "desc") {
  this.setState({
    desc: e.target.value
  });
}
```