# Map function and React setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React.

I need to update property of object in a state.
I try to use the code below and faced an error.

Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong.

```
export interface IResultSourcesListItemsState {
  listitems: [
{
  "Title": string,
  "sourceGuid": string,
  "isChecked": boolean
}
  ]
}
```

_

```
public constructor(props: IResultSourcesProps, state: IResultSourcesListItemsState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listitems: [
        {
          "Title": "",
          "sourceGuid": "",
          "isChecked": true
         }
       ],
     };
     ResultSources.siteUrl = this.props.webSiteUrl;
}

resultSourceValueChange(checked, value) {
    let stateChanged = false;
    const updatedState = this.state.listitems.map((listitem) => {
      if (listitem.Title === "All" && listitem.isChecked) {
        listitem.isChecked = false;
        stateChanged = true;
      }
      return listitem;
    });
    if (stateChanged)
      this.setState({listitems: updatedState});
}
```

[image]

I simplified my code,
now this code is working

```
const updatedState = this.state.listitems;
this.setState({listitems: updatedState});
```

but this code is not compyling, why?

```
const updatedState = [...this.state.listitems];
this.setState({listitems: updatedState});
```

Comment: Why you need `stateChanged ` variable?

Comment: To update state only if something was changed

Comment: Can you add full code. Generally you can do that using `componentDidUpdate`. Codesandbox of this is helpful. Just add bare minimum code there.  Its easy to debug if we have live code

Comment: It is a big project with many dependencies. it is not so easy to copy it to playground :(

Comment: What's the error coming for second one. Its looks like your data is not `spreadable ` then. If its giving error

Comment: I edited post. One question why const updatedState = [...this.state.listitems]; this.setState({listitems: updatedState}); is not working? the same but without coppying array is working. const updatedState = this.state.listitems;

Comment: The same error as in the picture

Comment: Can you include the code where you define IResultSourcesListItemsState?

Comment: @frangaren included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved my issue.

I jusd add `as any`. So the line is

```
this.setState({listitems: updatedState} as any);
```

or

```
this.setState({listitems: updatedState} as Pick<IResultSourcesListItemsState, keyof IResultSourcesListItemsState>);
```

I don't know why it occurs.
[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361905/property-is-missing-in-type-x-string-string) was helpful for me.

Comment: Check my answer, you can solve your error with that, but you have some misconceptions and your code is still not correctly defined.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the error I thought you had when I asked for the definition of `IResultSourcesListItemsState`. Your error is related to TypeScript, not React.

When you use the syntax `let foo:[string] = ...` foo is a tuple with a single element (a list that always has a single element). For example, `let bar:[string, string, string] = ...` would have always three elements. If you want to define a "normal" list you have to use the syntax `let baz:string[] = ...`.

Since the return value of `map` is a list, not a tuple, and the type of `listitems` in your state is a tuple, you get an error. TypeScript can't guarantee that the return of `map` will always have a single element, and so the type is incompatible with the one of your `listitems` property.

To fix this, you want to redefine your interface `IResultSourcesListItemsState` as follows:

```
export interface IResultSourcesListItemsState {
  listitems: {
     "Title": string,
     "sourceGuid": string,
     "isChecked": boolean
  }[]
}
```

As a side note, here you are mutating your state directly on the map function and that is a bad practice:

```
resultSourceValueChange(checked, value) {
    let stateChanged = false;
    const updatedState = this.state.listitems.map((listitem) => {
      if (listitem.Title === "All" && listitem.isChecked) {
        listitem.isChecked = false;
        stateChanged = true;
      }
      return listitem;
    });
    if (stateChanged)
      this.setState({listitems: updatedState});
}
```

Comment: Thank you @frangaren ! Your answer is working. But I took example of interface from MS - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37948.sharepoint-framework-retrieve-and-display-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api-and-react-js.aspx. Try to find IReactGetItemsState

Comment: Why you said that I mutate the state? As I know The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.  This method does not change the original array. Am I right?

Comment: Your a correct about `map`, but `listitem.isChecked = false;` does mutate the item in the list.

Comment: thanks! How to avoid it? How I should redesign code to avoid mutating?

Comment: Instead of `listitem.isChecked = false;`, you can use `return {...listitem, isChecked: false};` which creates a copy of the listitem but with `isChecked` attribute as `false`. You can add several properties. Keep in mind that the properties are applied in order so `return {isChecked: false, ...listitem};'  would keep the `isChecked` value of  `listitem`. Also, read [this](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1) because you can run into problems if you mutate your state based on your previous state the way you are doing it.